# Getting Socket closed error when a remoting exception is thrown on the server

Tags: .net, exception, sockets, remoting

I have an app that is built using .Net remoting. When authenticating, If there is an error, I threw an exception on the server. The exception is serializable. But when the exception is thrown on the server, Sometimes I see an error on the client side that says "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine".

This is the stack trace I have from windbg when try to debug the server. Looks like the remoting framework is doing that. Any ideas as to why the socket is being closed and how to handle this?

```
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Close()
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.Close()
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.CloseOnFatalError(System.Exception)
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.ProcessRequestNow()
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RequestQueue.ProcessNextRequest(System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler)
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.BeginReadMessageCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(System.Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)
System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)
System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

Comment: If you post some code, you may have better success with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the case that the .Net remoting framework closes the socket everytime a remoting exception is thrown? from debugging using WinDbg, that looks to the case. Could some one confirm this? Also, Is it the case some times the socket is closed after the reponse is sent and sometimes the socket is closed before the response is sent depending on an particular scenario?

This is trace from windbg on the client side when I don't get that "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". In this case, I get a remoting exception

```
06d2f45c 7c812aeb [HelperMethodFrame: 06d2f45c] 
06d2f500 7a5ff43e System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)
06d2f51c 67777fb0 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
06d2f530 67777b12 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.ReadFromSocket(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
06d2f540 67777aea System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.BufferMoreData()
06d2f548 67777a7c System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
06d2f56c 67777998 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.ReadAndMatchFourBytes(Byte[])
06d2f578 67783199 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpSocketHandler.ReadVersionAndOperation(UInt16 ByRef)
06d2f598 67783ece System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientSocketHandler.ReadHeaders()
06d2f5b4 67782456 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders, System.IO.Stream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders ByRef, System.IO.Stream ByRef)
06d2f5d0 06e61bdf com.imageright.security.remoting.IdentityClientSink.ProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders, System.IO.Stream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders ByRef, System.IO.Stream ByRef)
06d2f5f0 6778ae69 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
06d2f62c 793c319f System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.CallProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.ArrayWithSize, System.Threading.Thread, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, Boolean)
06d2f650 793c2f82 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.InternalInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage, Boolean, Int32)
06d2f6b4 793c2db9 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
06d2f6c4 79374dc3 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData ByRef, Int32)
06d2f960 79f98b43 [TPMethodFrame: 06d2f960] com.imageright.server.IInstrumentation.GetEnterpriseID()
06d2f970 06e618ee imageright.proxies_com.imageright.server.IInstrumentationProxy.GetEnterpriseID()
06d2f9c4 069fddae ImageRight.EMC.EnterpriseNode.EstablishConnection()
06d2fa00 069fdce7 ImageRight.EMC.RootNode.TryOpenConnections(System.Object)
06d2fa38 79407caa System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
06d2fa3c 79373ecd System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
06d2fa54 79407e18 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback)
06d2fa68 79407d90 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(System.Object)
06d2fbf8 79e7c74b [GCFrame: 06d2fbf8]
```

This is the trace when I get that error "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". In this case I get a socket error.

```
06d2f45c 7c812aeb [HelperMethodFrame: 06d2f45c] 
06d2f500 7a5ff43e System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)
06d2f51c 67777fb0 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
06d2f530 67777b12 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.ReadFromSocket(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
06d2f540 67777aea System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.BufferMoreData()
06d2f548 67777a7c System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
06d2f56c 67777998 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.ReadAndMatchFourBytes(Byte[])
06d2f578 67783199 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpSocketHandler.ReadVersionAndOperation(UInt16 ByRef)
06d2f598 67783ece System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientSocketHandler.ReadHeaders()
06d2f5b4 67782456 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders, System.IO.Stream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders ByRef, System.IO.Stream ByRef)
06d2f5d0 06e61bdf com.imageright.security.remoting.IdentityClientSink.ProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders, System.IO.Stream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders ByRef, System.IO.Stream ByRef)
06d2f5f0 6778ae69 System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
06d2f62c 793c319f System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.CallProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.ArrayWithSize, System.Threading.Thread, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, Boolean)
06d2f650 793c2f82 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.InternalInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage, Boolean, Int32)
06d2f6b4 793c2db9 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
06d2f6c4 79374dc3 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData ByRef, Int32)
06d2f960 79f98b43 [TPMethodFrame: 06d2f960] com.imageright.server.IInstrumentation.GetEnterpriseID()
06d2f970 06e618ee imageright.proxies_com.imageright.server.IInstrumentationProxy.GetEnterpriseID()
06d2f9c4 069fddae ImageRight.EMC.EnterpriseNode.EstablishConnection()
06d2fa00 069fdce7 ImageRight.EMC.RootNode.TryOpenConnections(System.Object)
06d2fa38 79407caa System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
06d2fa3c 79373ecd System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
06d2fa54 79407e18 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback)
06d2fa68 79407d90 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(System.Object)
06d2fbf8 79e7c74b [GCFrame: 06d2fbf8].
```

And the one that is throwing the exception on the server is our custom sink that takes care of security. I could have posted the code If it as in one place and straight forward.